# Starting to use OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl

I want to use SSL in my cross platform program. I decided to use OpenSSL.

I have OpenSSL installed, and at this point I am looking through the code and documentation trying to figure out how to use the library.

Do you have any resources or simple programs or tutorials that will walk me through integrating OpenSSL with my program?

Comment: You might want to make your question a bit more specific.

Comment: Are you using OpenSSL to write an SSL client, or an SSL server?

Comment: I have a client and server, and I need to add ssl support. So, both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very rough guide is:

- Create a new `SSL_CTX` with [`SSL_CTX_new()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html#);
- *(server only)* Load the certificate with [`SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html#);
- *(server only)* Load the private key with [`SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html#);
- Establish the network connection;
- Create a new `SSL` with [`SSL_new()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_new.html#);
- Set the file descriptor of the `SSL` to that of your network connection with [`SSL_set_fd()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_set_fd.html#);
- *(client only)* Call [`SSL_connect()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html#);
- *(server only)* Call [`SSL_accept()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_accept.html#).

Thereafter use [`SSL_read()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_read.html#) and [`SSL_write()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_write.html#) to read and write from the connection, and finish with [`SSL_shutdown()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html#).  The `SSL_CTX` can be re-used to create `SSL` objects for many simultaneous sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some useful OpenSSL commands on this page:

http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/ssl+certificates/manuals/openssl/openssl+commands/

Comment: I would like to be able to programatically use the library. As in, add the library to my c++ project and integrate it with my code. As far as my programming knowledge goes,  I cant do it using that command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

from the "very rough guide" you mentioned, i managed to reach till successful SSL handshake, between mozilla web browser and my server(coded in c).But after SSL_accept, when am trying to use SSL_read to get the browser header details, am getting junk values and the bytes read are shown to be zero. below is the code, the SSL_accept call is successful but SSL_read is not..

```
    if(SSL_set_fd(ssl, client_s)<0)
        printf("\n error in assigning socket to SSL:");
    else
        printf("\n The socket has been assigned to SSL Structure");

    /* Perform SSL Handshake on the SSL server */
    err = SSL_accept(ssl);
    printf("\n Value of err is %d",err);
    RETURN_ERR(err,"SSL_accept");
    if(err==1)
        printf("\n The ssl connection/Handshake has been successful");
    else
        printf("\n The ssl connection was not successful");

    /* Informational output (optional) */
        printf("\n SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher (ssl));


    /*receive the data from the client*/
    //err = SSL_accept(ssl);
    while(i<5)
    {
        err = SSL_read(ssl, in_buf, strlen(in_buf));
        printf("\n value of err is %d",err);
        RETURN_ERR(err,"SSL_read");

        printf("\n The details from the server is\n: %s,\n Bytes Read : %d",in_buf,err);
        if(err<0)
        printf("\n Not Successfully received clients information");
        i++;
     }
     err = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    /* Terminate communication on a socket */
    err = close(server_s);
    /* Free the SSL structure */
    SSL_free(ssl);
    /* Free the SSL_CTX structure */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return(0);
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to add `<pre><code>` if you indend your code with 4 spaces.